# Drupal 7 AJAX error

Tags: 7, ajax

I'm getting this AJAX error when I try to manually check for updates. I also get AJAX errors when I upload an image, remove a image, use the taxonomy auto generate field: juse about anything that uses AJAX. I have two other installations of Drupal 7 on the same server, so it's not a server configuration; they all have the same modules enabled, so it's not a module problem. I don't know what it is.
What's the best way to debug AJAX? I have never needed in my life to debug AJAX, but this is causing a big problem with my website. it would be a pain to start over now.

This is the error I get:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows.
>   Path: /batch?render=overlay&id=3&op=do
>   StatusText: OK
>   ResponseText: {"status":true,"percentage":"33","message":"Trying to check available update data ...\u003cbr \/\u003eChecked available update data for \u003cem class=\"placeholder\"\u003eDevel\u003c\/em\u003e."} Drupal for Firebug General Messages There were no messages sent to the general log.
>   Please use "firep($item, $optional_title)" to output messages to this console.
>   Query Logging is Not Enabled
>   Please enable "Collect query info" in the Devel Module Settings (admin/settings/devel) to use this feature. There was no form altering. There was no user processing. There was no node
>   processing. The views module is not installed. There was no page processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to disable the Drupal for Firebug module or fix it so that it doesn't return something on an ajax call.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. But I use the heck out of FireBug for drupal is there a another easy way to get drupal info like node arrays and stuff.

Comment: Check out devel.module and the dpm() and ddebug_backtrace() functions. You could also fix the Drupal for Firebug module, you just need to make sure to not return that stuff for ajax calls. deve.modue has exactly the same problem, have a look at devel_exit().

Comment: I am having the same problem and no idea how to do this."disable the Drupal for Firebug module or fix it so that it doesn't return something on an ajax call". Please help

Comment: @webrole: You probably figured out how to disable a module by now; in the case you have not, go to admin/modules and uncheck the box before the "Drupal for Firebug" and "Drupal for Firebug Preprocessor" modules (you will have to do this in two steps).

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by uncommenting the max_input_vars=1000 field in the php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by upgrading to PHP 5.4
(I only experienced this issue with PHP 5.3, with Drupal 7)

Comment: I bet Drupal 7 is not yet compatible with PHP 5.4.

Comment: I've run Drupal 7 with PHP 5.4, most modules work fine.